# ADC signal close to D+/D- signals layout suggestion

Tags: adc, noise, layout, interference, ftdi

My circuit is laid out in way so that the analog front end is on a different pcb than the MCU board.

The two PCBs are connected with a vertical connector of which 4 pins are used to transfer two low frequency (<50 Hz) ADC signals and their return current.

**My question** is whether you think the D+ and D- signals from the USB connector going to the FTDI chip will affect the ADC signals in terms of crosstalk/noise.

My estimate is that, even though the actual signals are relatively seperated, the  high frequency return paths of the USB signals will be spreading quite a lot affecting the ADC lines.

The alternatives I have in mind are either leaving the layout as it is or placing the GND pins for the ADC signal somewhere on the left side of the connector, further apart from D+,D-.

- Note that I cannot change the position of the ADC1,ADC2 signals.
- But I can rearrange some things up north to push USB connector further up slightly.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

[image: ADC lines and return paths close to D+,D- highlighted in yellow]

EDIT:

Ok, after the suggestions in the comments and th answer I've updated the layout to increase the distance even more between the signals in question and not use the connector's pads as a path for the data lines.
Also, I added a small cut-out in the top ground layer on the left but I doubt it makes a huge difference.

The question that arises now is should I place a bigger cutout in the bottom ground plane, right there between ADC and Data lines?

[image: Edited Layout]

Comment: Would it be possible to add filters in your design? Adding a low-pass filter could be a good idea.

Comment: Why are your USB signals going two different places?  That should generally be avoided.  Put some ferrites and caps on the ADC signals, but do keep the load impedance of the ADC input in mind.

Comment: @ChrisStratton ah, I should have indicated that. They are not going two different places, they are simply using two pads of the connector to pass from the USB on the right , to the FTDI chip on top.

Comment: I'd suggest you not use connector pads as through-routing paths, especially for a high speed (in the context of your board) differential pair.

Comment: thank you, I'll pass them from above the connector and remove one of the FT5V tracks so they fit.

Comment: Why do you think a cutout would help?  If anything, why not ground the unused connector pins?

Comment: I would think the cutout would prevent the return currents of the datal lines being in the vicinity of the return currents of the ADC line.

And that's why I haven't yet grounded the rest of the pins, because I don't want the return current of the ADC lines to be spread throughout the pins, rather stay in that restricted area formed by only the two ground pins next to the ADC signals. But I'm skeptical about this reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electric Field coupling ABOVE A PLANE is proportional to 1 / distance^3.

Electric Fields will happily divert (most of the electric flux) to nearby metal regions, strongly attenuating the remote flux coupling. But the Fields still exploit ALL POSSIBLE paths, thus your remote coupling is never reduced to Zero. That said, large nearby pieces of metal (tied to GND or to VDD) are your friend.

Push those interfering signal further to the right.

Push those vulnerable ADC inputs further to the left.

And, crucially, widen that Grounded-region between the interferers and the vulnerable traces.

Comment: Thank you, I'll definately do the first and last suggestion of yours but unfortunately cannot, move the ADC signals. Does it matter where the returns paths of those ADC signals are compared to those of the data lines? On that note, would it make sense to split the green ground plane in between them?

Comment: YES to your new layout.